# Google Tag Manager Filters for View Home Page (Best Practice)

Tags: best-practices, google-tag-manager

When using Google Tag Manager you have various tags, triggers and filters. If you want to use the Page View [firing Trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en) with a filter only for the home page which one is more politically correct:

- Page Path `/`
- Page URL `https://www.example.com`
- Page Hostname `www.example.com`

Comment: [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en) uses `url equals example.com/index.html` for a home page trigger.

Comment: I've tried without `www.` and `https://`, sadly there examples are vague and not exact. I very much doubt it would work with index.html for a site that does not have one.

Comment: I agree about that.   I've never used GTM, but in GA, `Page Path /` works reliably.

Comment: GTM rocks for Schema JSON-LD learning the varibles now, so much easier than messing around with inline code.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is Page URL equals to url_of_main page. Other variants can contain pages on different hosts or on entire host.

Comment: Should the URL of the main page end in a slash, or not for GTM?

Comment: It can be just /. You can always check what is stored in variables using debug window in GTM.